# Ricochets dоn't wоrk prоperly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I want to make ricochet for my bullet. But when my bullet collides with a wall, bullet starts to fly along wall:

[image]

What did I do wrong? Here are my code parts:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 m_dir;

private void Start()
    {

        m_dir = rb.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right);
        rb.velocity = m_dir * speed;
    }

 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            Vector2 _wallNormal = col.contacts[0].normal;
            m_dir = Vector2.Reflect(rb.velocity, _wallNormal).normalized;
            Debug.Log("Collide!"); // debug works
            rb.velocity = m_dir * speed;
        }
    }
```

Bullet Inspector - `CircleCollider2D` + `Rigidbody2D`. Wall Inspector - `BoxCollider2D` + `Rigidbody 2D (Kinematic)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all:**
The default behavior in Unity physics should already ricochet the bullet from the wall without your help.
As the bullet collider is round, it should not fly in a random direction.

**What causes your problem:**
The problem you have, seems to come from the order in which the methods are called.
Basically unity physics first resolves the collisions for this physics frame, and afterwards calls all the OnCollisionEnter methods. ([More information](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Event_Execution_Order))
This causes your *rb.velocity* to already be the ricochet velocity.
When you now calculate the reflect angle with the velocity pointing away from the wall, you get an inward pointing velocity.
In essence, your bullet keeps on ricocheting from the wall, but you change direction back to the wall in every frame.

**How to solve it:**
Use the [Collision2d.relativeVelocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-relativeVelocity.html) instead of *rb.velocity*.
This is the velocity that was recordet at the time of impact instead of the changed one.
Note: As it is relative to an unmoving object, you get the absolute velocity.

```
m_dir = Vector2.Reflect(rb.velocity, _wallNormal).normalized;
```

becomes

```
m_dir = Vector2.Reflect(-col.relativeVelocity, _wallNormal).normalized;
```

Comment: Not solved. Now it goes down, not up (watch screenshot)

Comment: Which screenshot do you mean?  
I don't see any screenshot showing a bullet going down.

Comment: In the question. But bullet goes down, not up

Comment: The documentation is unclear on who is the originator of the relative velocity. Seems like it is the wall. Just negate the relativeVelocity, then it should work. Please let me know if it helps, then I can correct my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works! I'm very happy. Correct answer and then I will accept this answer